# Clearcontents of range without selecting it

Tags: excel

I am trying to clear contents of whole range with using .End to specify my range so i reduce the hassle of specifying the range each time for each sheet.

Here is the code :

```
Public Function clear(ws_clear As Worksheet, first_cell As String)
    ws_clear.Range(first_cell).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown).ClearContents
End Function
```

But this does not work and i dont know how to clear all non-empty cells from a single cell in the corner.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to select the required range first. Currently, you're selecting only one cell. Refer to `Range.Resize` method.

Comment: A function is used for calculations, not to clear cells